# Insert object element into array in ordered position, without using sort algorithm in Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, insert

I have  programming projectת I have it *almost* finished, but I am struggling on inserting a new object made from the console into the array at the correct position.

I can make the object, insert at either the beginning or end, delete object, etc. but the array needs to be in order (month, day, time) and I am stuck. 

I have been searching for a good day and a half, through forums, info websites, books, etc. and cannot find an answer.

P.S. I am NOT allowed to use anything other than an array (ArrayList, LinkedList, etc), and i cannot use any sorting algorithms (bubblesort, insertionsort, etc.)

Directions call specifically for me to shift array elements as needed and put new object in between/at correct position. Also I am using NetBeans.

```
    /*
 * 
 * 
 */
package project1;

import UserInput.UserInput;

public class Schedule {

    Delivery[] deliObj = new Delivery[20];

    int count = 0;

    public Schedule(){//set default objects 
        deliObj[0] = new Delivery("MAR", 4, 17, 30, "Pizza");
        count++;
        deliObj[1] = new Delivery("APR", 1, 06, 30, "Special Deliery");
        count++;
        deliObj[2] = new Delivery("MAY", 6, 12, 00, "Amazon (Books)");
        count++;
        deliObj[3] = new Delivery("JUN", 3, 11, 15, "Car Parts");
        count++;

    }
    public void setDelivery(Delivery[] deliObj){
        this.deliObj = deliObj;

    }
    public Delivery[] getDelivery(){
        return this.deliObj;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
            Schedule scheduleObj = new Schedule();
            scheduleObj.run();
    }

    public void run(){
        System.out.println("\n***** MAIN DELIVERY CONSOLE *****\n");
        System.out.println("A)dd delivery");            
        System.out.println("D)delete Delivery");           
        System.out.println("L)ist Delivery");           
        System.out.println("E)xit");
        char selection = Character.toUpperCase(UserInput.getChar());

        switch(selection){
            case 'A': addDelivery();                          
                break;
            case 'D': deleteDelivery();
                break;
            case 'L': listDelivery();
                break; 
            case 'E': System.exit(0); 

        }

    }    

    public void addDelivery(){
        Delivery getInputDelivery = new Delivery();
        getInputDelivery.InputDelivery();
        deliObj[count] = getInputDelivery;
        count++;
        insertDelivery(getInputDelivery);
        run();
    }

    public void deleteDelivery(){


    System.out.println("Please enter the number you wish to delete: ");
    int num = UserInput.getInt(0,count);
    //deliObj[num-1] = new Delivery();            
        deliObj[num-1] = null;
        count--;
        run();
    }

    public void listDelivery(){

        for(int i=0;i<count;i++) {

            System.out.println(i+1 + ". " + deliObj[i]);
        }
        run();
    }       

    public boolean compareDelivery(Delivery A1, Delivery A2){
        //Delivery delivery = deliObj[count-4];
        int numMonth;
        int numMonth1;

        numMonth = Delivery.integerMonth(A1.getMonth());
        numMonth1 = Delivery.integerMonth(A2.getMonth());

        if(numMonth < numMonth1){
            return true;
        }
        else if(numMonth == numMonth1){
            if(A1.getDay() < A2.getDay()){
                return true;
            }
            else if(A1.getDay() == A2.getDay()){
                if(A1.getHour() < A2.getHour()){
                    return true;
                }
                else if(A1.getHour() == A2.getHour()){
                    if(A1.getMintute() < A2.getMintute()){
                        return true;
                    }
               }
            }
        } //else return false; 

        return false;
    }

    public void insertDelivery(Delivery temp){



        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
           /*if(!compareDelivery(deliObj[i], temp)) {
                for(int k = 1; k < count; k++) {
                    Delivery temp2 = deliObj[k];
                deliObj[k] = deliObj[count-1];
                deliObj[count-1] = temp2;
                }*/
           if(compareDelivery(deliObj[i], temp)) {

                Delivery temp2 = deliObj[i];
                deliObj[i] = deliObj[count-1];
                deliObj[count-1] = temp2;


            }

        }
       /*for (int k = 0; k < count-1; k++) { 
             if(compareDelivery(deliObj[k], temp)) {
                 Delivery temp2 = deliObj[k];
                deliObj[k] = deliObj[count-1];
                deliObj[count-1] = temp2;
                //deliObj[count] = deliObj[k];
                //deliObj[k] = deliObj[count-1];

            }                            
            } */
    }



}
```

this is my main class where things are run, but here is the other subclass that has the constructors and getters/setters etc.

```
package project1;

import UserInput.UserInput;

public class Delivery {

private static final String FINAL_MONTH[] = {"JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"};
private String month;
private int day;
private int hour;
private int minute;
private int second;
private String userMessage;

public static int integerMonth(String compareMonth){
    for(int i = 0; i < FINAL_MONTH.length; i++){
        if(compareMonth.equals(FINAL_MONTH[i])){
            return i;
        }                
    }
    return -1;
}

public Delivery(String month, int day, int hour, int minute, String userMessage) {
    this.month = month;
    this.day = day;
    this.hour = hour;
    this.minute = minute;
    this.userMessage = userMessage;
}

public void setMonth(String month) {

    for (String FINAL_MONTH1 : FINAL_MONTH) {
        if (month.equalsIgnoreCase(FINAL_MONTH1)) {
            this.month = month.toUpperCase();
        }
    }
}

public String getMonth() {
    return this.month;
}

public void setDay(int day) {
    this.day = day;
}

public int getDay() {
    return this.day;
}

public void setHour(int hour) {
    this.hour = hour;
}

public int getHour() {
    return this.hour;
}

public void setMinute(int minute) {
    this.minute = minute;
}

public int getMintute() {
    return this.minute;
}

public void setSecond(int second) {
    this.second = second;
}

public int getSecond() {
    return this.second;
}

public void setUserMessage(String userMessage) {
    this.userMessage = userMessage;
}

public String getUserMessage() {
    return this.userMessage;
}

public Delivery() {
    month = "JAN";
    day = 1;
    hour = 12;
    minute = 00; 
    userMessage = "default";

}

@Override
public String toString() {
    String data = String.format(month + " %02d, " + "%02d:" + "%02d " + userMessage, day, hour, minute);
    return data;
}

public void InputDelivery() {
    System.out.println("Enter month of delivery(3 letter abbreviation): ");
    setMonth(UserInput.getString(3, 3));
    System.out.println("Enter day of delivery: ");
    setDay(UserInput.getInt(0, 31));
    System.out.println("Enter hour of delivery (0-23): ");
    setHour(UserInput.getInt(0, 24));
    System.out.println("Enter minute of delivery (0-59): ");
    setMinute(UserInput.getInt(0, 59));
    System.out.println("Enter message for delivery (40 Character Max): ");
    setUserMessage(UserInput.getString(0,40));
    System.out.println(toString());

}



}
```

I really need help with just the insertDelivery() method, if you see other errors you can mention them but please try to just advise me on that portion!

Comment: You are probably looking for [Arrays.binarySearch()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28T[],%20T,%20java.util.Comparator%29). *Returns: index of the search key, if it is contained in the array; otherwise, **(-(insertion point) - 1)***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll start by assuming that  "anything other than an array" does not extend to utility classes such as `java.util.Arrays`. If it does, you will need to implement some the method I use below your self.

---

The first step is to either make your `Delivery` implement `Comparable<Delivery>` or make a new class that implements `Comparator<Delivery>`. This defines an ordering for your `Delivery` object. This change should be simple because you have already defined a `compareDelivery` method.

With this modification made, you can get the index of at which to insert the value by calling `Arrays.binarySearch(deliObj,temp)`. If you aren't allowed to use the `Arrays` class, [this link](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~reid/search/bincode.html) show a simple binary search implementation.

> ```
> 1    int[] data;
> 2    int size;
> 3
> 4    public boolean binarySearch(int key) 
> 5    {
> 6         int low = 0;
> 7         int high = size - 1;
> 8          
> 9         while(high >= low) {
> 10             int middle = (low + high) / 2;
> 11             if(data[middle] == key) {
> 12                 return true;
> 13             }
> 14             if(data[middle] < key) {
> 15                 low = middle + 1;
> 16             }
> 17             if(data[middle] > key) {
> 18                 high = middle - 1;
> 19             }
> 20        }
> 21        return false;
> 22   }
> ```

Having this index, you now need to insert your object at this point. Using arrays however, this is slightly more difficult than it seems. The length of an Array is immutable, so you have to create a new Array that is one element longer than your current array before inserting the object. You'll be doing what happens behind the scenes in `ArrayList`, more or less.Inserting an element into an array has been covered on StackOverflow before, so I'll just refer you to [a helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11638208/3179747).

> ```
> public static int[] addPos(int[] a, int pos, int num) {
>     int[] result = new int[a.length];
>     for(int i = 0; i < pos; i++)
>         result[i] = a[i];
>     result[pos] = num;
>     for(int i = pos + 1; i < a.length; i++)
>         result[i] = a[i - 1];
>     return result;
> }
> ```

Comment: confused about implementing my 'compareDelivery()' in 'Delivery' class. Shouldn't i just be able to call 'compareDelivery()' during the 'insertDelivery()'? And also, how do I find the index that the 'binarySearch' returns? Once I find that do I just do the swap how I have it, although of course with the correct indices being swapped? I thought it required complete shift of array...

Comment: @Camdeazy what I mean with the `compare` method in delivery is that you should change the class declaration for `Delivery` to `public class Delivery implements Comparable<Delivery>` then in the body of the class add a method `public int compare(Delivery d)` that contains the same logic as your `compareDelivery` method. This allows you to use `java.util.Arrays` method that require a natural ordering for the elements of an array.  The binary search can be moddifued to return the index by replacing `return true` to `return middle` and `return false` to `return -1`.

Answer (score 0):

In general you cannot **insert** an element into an array. Arrays are fixed length (they contain exactly `n` elements and you cannot alter an array to contain `n+1` or `n-1` elements). What you can do is create a new array that has space for `n+1`elements and copy the elements from the original array into the new array inserting the new element in the correct place as you create it. You can also create it to be too large in anticipation of getting more elements (looks like what you have done) and then start to shift the elements up.

This sounds like a homework question. Are you able to ask a someone (a lab helper, tutor, co-student) if you have the right idea? The requirements "I am NOT allowed to use anything other than an array" and the need to insert seem at odds.

Comment: I can which is what i will do tomorrow, but sadly the few I have asked already were unwilling to help beyond vague "advice" and wouldn't actually help me with code. the TA i asked is the same way, like i should know b/c of the class I'm in. it sucks really. and the requirements are for array of 20 elements, but only put 4 in as default, then ability to add/delete up to the 20 limit. I agree that its at odds, that's why im having so much difficulty. Thanks for the quick reply though, means a lot