# How is insertion for a Singly Linked List and Doubly Linked List constant time?

Tags: time-complexity, singly-linked-list

Thinking about it, I thought the time complexity for insertion and search for any data structure should be the same, because to insert, you first have to search for the location you want to insert, and then you have to insert.

According to here: http://bigocheatsheet.com/, for a linked list, search is linear time but insertion is constant time. I understand how searching is linear (start from the front, then keep going through the nodes on the linked list one after another until you find what you are searching for), but how is insertion constant time?

Suppose I have this linked list:

```
1 -> 5 -> 8 -> 10 -> 8
```

and I want to insert the number 2 after the number 8, then would I have to first search for the number 8 (search is linear time), and then take an extra 2 steps to insert it (so, insertion is still linear time?)?

```
#insert y after x in python 
def insert_after(x, y):
    search_for(y)
    y.next = x.next
    x.next = y
```

Edit: Even for a doubly linked list, shouldn't it still have to search for the node first (which is linear time), and then insert?

Comment: http://bigocheatsheet.com/ happens to be my go-to website as well for running-time complexities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So if you already have a reference to the node you are trying to insert then it is `O(1)`. Otherwise, it is `search_time + O(1)`. It is a bit misleading but [on wikipedia](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Linked_list#/Singly_linked_lists) there is a chart explains it a bit better:
[image]

Contrast this to a dynamic array, which, if you want to insert at the beginning is: `Θ(n)`.

Just for emphasis: The website you reference is referring to the actual act of inserting given we already know where we want to insert.

Comment: Well if we have a reference to the data / node, then shouldn't the insertion time complexity of Any data structure where insertion is possible be O(1)? For example, in a skip list, if we have reference to a node (called 'node'), and want to insert y after 'node', then we can just do y.next = node.next and then node.next = y. Isn't that O(1) as well?

Comment: No, look at the case of inserting at the beginning of a dynamic array. We know where the beginning is (hopefully lol). In a list we just point to what is next, in an array we have to shift all the elements over, so it takes Θ(n) time.

Comment: @user2719875: Also FWIW, skip list take log(n)... The array example is easier to illustrate though.

Comment: hm, take a look at the top answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638123/how-to-add-an-element-to-array-and-shift-indexes. In 6 steps, any number can be inserted at any location (even if it is the beginning of the array). Isn't that constant time as well?

Comment: nevermind, ignore my question in the comment above. I just realized the for loop which repeats until the length of the array is reached = linear time.

Answer (score 1):

Time to insert = Time to set three pointers = O(3) = constant time.

Time to insert the data is not the same as time to insert the data at a particular location. The time asked is the time to *insert the data* only.