# Insert and Splice error in java

Tags: java, arrays, random, insert, splice

I'm trying to Insert some random numbers with the same index in an array but something doesn't work. It says "cannot find symbol". This error is the same with Insert and Splice

the code:

```
   Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);  
   System.out.println("Quina llargada tindrà la taula? ");
   int n = reader.nextInt(); //n=llargada taula
   int[] taula = new int[n];
   int ultims = n-21;


   int fi = 100*n;
   Random rand = new Random();
   //int al = rand.nextInt(fi) + 0;

   for (int i = 0; i < taula.length; i++) 
       taula[i] = rand.nextInt(fi);

 Random randGromulls = new Random();
   for (int g = 0; g < 10; g++) {
       g++;
       int k = randGromulls.nextInt(10);
       int igual = k;
       taula.Insert(k, igual);
       //taula.splice(k, 0, igual); this does not work either

   }
```

Comment: Java doesn't have splice or insert for arrays. Also, `Insert`? That doesn't follow Java naming conventions.

Comment: Which symbol can't it find? Did you bother Googling the error? You're using methods that don't exist I think. Solution: Don't use methods that don't exist.

Comment: what is taula actually?

Comment: sorry, taula is and array

Comment: well that's not helpfull. im not using methods that dont exist, i just have not copied all the code. Taula is an array

Comment: @Marco Yes, you are. Insert and Splice just plain don't exist for Array in java.

Comment: @tnw so Insert is not a method in java?

Comment: @Marco Not for `Array`, no. Did you [read the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html)? I have no idea where you're getting your information that says they do exist. Next time please make some more research effort before asking.

Comment: Read this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html . You can  access the array index and set the value, similar to this array[index] = 10;

Comment: @tnw from another questions, but maybe i misunderstood with some other kind of arrays, dont know. You know how i can do what i'm trying?

Comment: @Marco: edit your question code so that you define the taula variable. And ask clearly what is your goal. Maybe you need to use ArrayList.

Comment: @Marco Come on. Please just Google it. All you have to do is Google "java array insert" and "java array splice".

Comment: @Macro, you want to insert the element and shift the index of array ? Is this your objective ?

Comment: @tnw oh man i have been trying it for an hour. asking this here is the last option. my main lenguage is not english so its difficult to me. Thanks for nothing

Comment: @Marco Seriously? I answered your questions AND pointed you in the right direction to get the more in depth questions answered.

Comment: @ThanigaiArasu hey. well i'm trying to add a number in an array full of randoms. This numbers thati'm trying to add need to have the same index like: {4, 8, 13, 17, 21}
i want to add a 3, so -> {4, 8, 13, 3, 17, 21}

Comment: @ThanigaiArasu also, sorry for bad english

Comment: @Marco Okay. Did you Google "java array insert" as I recommended?

Comment: @tnw yes but all i get is add(). but i found that add() only adds indexs at the end of an array

Comment: @Marco This is literally the first result for "java array insert": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638123/how-to-add-an-element-to-array-and-shift-indexes

Answer (score 0):

The code you copied with `insert` and `splice` methods was for Javascript, not Java. Java arrays cannot change size. You probably want to use a [`List<Integer>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) instead.

If you really need an array, you can simulate insertion by shifting the array data to the next index:

```
System.arraycopy(array, i, array, i + 1, array.length - i - 1);
array[i] = value;
```

For example, when you insert the value 5 at index 2, it does this:

```
 |0|1|2|3|4|0|0|0|
      \ \ \ \ \ x
       \ \ \ \ \
 |0|1|2|2|3|4|0|0| System.arraycopy (shift by 1)
      v
 |0|1|5|2|3|4|0|0| array[2] = 5
```

The last element of the array is dropped, since Java arrays cannot change size. You'll need to create the array with enough extra space to hold the inserted elements.

Alternately, if you aren't worried about memory overhead, you could create a new array for each insert:

```
int[] array2 = new int[array.length + 1];
System.arraycopy(array, 0, array2, 0, i);
System.arraycopy(array, i, array2, i + 1, array.length - i);
array2[i] = value;
array = array2; // all references must be updated to the new array!
```

This would give you an array with a larger size, but the original array object won't be changed.